# How to do image stegnography in android

Tags: android, steganography

I want to hide a secrete message inside image.

I don't have any idea about algorithm used for this.Can any one please help me to give an idea how to implement it.

Comment: Stackoverflow is about questions not sharing code. Please convert your post to a question with a definite answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an app called [MobiStego](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mobistego/) which uses Steganography, it is open source.

Take a look through the files on the SVN at: [mobistego.svn.sourceforge.net](http://mobistego.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mobistego/MobiStegoAndorid/) it may be help you out.

Comment: Thank you...this application is good

Comment: @AbiAndroid: Then right my ans

Comment: @AbiAndroid: Pls follow me : http://niravranpara.blogspot.in/